# JTextArea: Limit string width and line count?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jtextarea, word-wrap

The user needs to enter text to be printed on a fixed-size label. Given a font, the label has a fixed number of lines and also a fixed width in pixels. How can I adapt a JTextArea (or something else in Swing, if there is another option) to this use case?

- Maximum number of lines
- Each line of characters not exceeding a certain pixel width
- Text wrapping from line to line at the word level for lines attempting to exceed the maximum pixel width

I have a PlainDocument that limits the length of a single line of text according to the width in pixels of the string, measured in capital Ws (the widest character in my font):

```
public class StandardDocument extends PlainDocument {

    /****** VARIABLES **********************************************/
    public boolean upperCase = true;
    private int textLimit;
    private int textWidth;
    private int fieldWidth;
    private JTextField textField = new JTextField();


    /** Get the maximum width of this text field, measured in capital Ws.
     *  @return textWidth - int
     **/
    public int getTextWidth() {
        return textWidth;
    }

    /** Get the maximum width of this text field, measured in pixels.
     *  @return textWidth - int
     **/
    protected int getFieldWidth() {
        return fieldWidth;
    }

    /** Core method for inserting value provided by user after "cleaning" user's value automatically. **/
    public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {

        if (str == null) { return; }

       // Set field value when value is within character limit of field.
        if (textWidth > 0) {
            int attemptedWidth = textField.getFontMetrics(Constants.defaultFontLabels).stringWidth(getText(0, getLength()) + str);
            if (attemptedWidth > fieldWidth) {
                return;
            }
        }

         // Set value in field.
        super.insertString(offs, str, attr);
    }

    /** Set the maximum text width as a maximum number of capital Ws this field may hold. **/
    public void setTextWidth(int wLimit) {
        if (wLimit >= 0) {
            textWidth = wLimit;
            StringBuffer outputBuffer = new StringBuffer(wLimit);
            for (int i = 0; i < wLimit; i++){
               outputBuffer.append("W");
            }
            fieldWidth = textField.getFontMetrics(Constants.defaultFontLabels).stringWidth(outputBuffer.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping is supported by a JTextArea. You turn it on using:

```
textArea.setLineWrap( true );
textArea.setWrapStyleWord( true );
```

The line count will be a little more difficult since you don't know if the newly added text will cause the line to wrap until the Document has been updated.

So maybe you need a cross edit that you can invoke when you click the "Print" button. Maybe you can use the `getWrappedLines(...)` method from the[Text Utilities](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/26/text-utilities/) class. If the wrapped lines is greater than the maximum you prevent the printing.

Or, maybe you automatically insert the text into the Document. Then you check the number of lines. If greater than the maximum you display a message and then invoke the `remove(...)` method right away.